# Marionette Layout doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm going through the docs and trying to set up a `Backbone.Marionette.Layout` in my application, but I keep getting a `Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined` error.

So I went through the source of the Marionette library on my server and couldn't find a definition for `Layout` anywhere. Which is odd since it's all over the docs. The `layoutView` works just fine and I can see the definition for that in the source.

I updated Maionette again, just to be sure I had the latest version, it's at 2.3.0 right now.

Here are some places where Layout is discussed as existing:

[The Marionette.js docs site](http://alchapone.github.io/marionette.doc/marionette/view/layout.html)

[Derick Baily's blog](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/22/managing-layouts-and-nested-views-with-backbone-marionette/)

I'm wondering if just a plain `Layout` has been deprecated, or if the docs are maybe using some sort of short hand and `layoutView` is actually what's being defined. Or if I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [version 2.0.0](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/releases), Layout has been renamed to LayoutView and here's the [current docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/current)

Comment: Thank you. Glad it was something that simple. I searched for deprecated marionette functions, but the results were not informative. And thanks for the link to the current docs.